# Custom domain name for azure website deployment slot?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I've got a web site on azure with a second deployment slot for staging. Let's say its `example.azurewebsites.net` and `example-staging.azurewebsites.net`. When I try to add a custom domain (i.e. `stage.example.com`), it tells me I must first make `stage.example.com` a CNAME of `example(staging).azurewebsites.net`. That last part... that doesn't work. Domains can't have ( and ) in them.. Is this a bug in Azure or am I missing something?

Comment: The message is wrong. Please refer to the message in the full Azure portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com/): "To verify authorization, create a CNAME resource record with your DNS provider that points from either www.yourdomain.com to example-staging.azurewebsites.net, or from awverify.www.yourdomain.com to awverify.example-staging.azurewebsites.net"

Comment: This was correct, but going a step further, the new portal seems to be validating against this incorrect rule as well. Even though I had the correct CNAME set up, the new portal would not allow me to add the domain, where the old portal did. If you want to repost your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Ok, reposted. Thanks. I will check that behavior in the new portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is wrong. Please refer to the message in the full Azure portal (manage.windowsazure.com): "To verify authorization, create a CNAME resource record with your DNS provider that points from either www.yourdomain.com to example-staging.azurewebsites.net, or from awverify.www.yourdomain.com to awverify.example-staging.azurewebsites.net.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the latest UX redesign for App Service custom domains.